# Javascript tabs, seo optimization

Tags: javascript, jquery, seo, tabs

I have page with tabs as content. Content of tabs isnt' loaded via ajax, it's just in code. Unactive tabs have set display: none.

The question is what see google bot? Does it see "hidden" content?  What about SEO in that case?

Is that a good solution tu put content to tabs? I think making a different subpage with poor (but similar) content isn't a good idea. So under the same URL tabs seem provide more and richer content... Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to check the text version of your google cache site

go to google.com and type the following : cache:http://www.your-domain.com

then click on : **Text-only version**

You will have a better idea on how google cache your site

Comment: Ok, but is text version exactly what bot see? Or are there any additional things?

Comment: if they have it on their cache it means they see it .

Comment: Of course the bot "sees" the content it's in the HTML after all. What is important is if they use what they see as part of the content ranking calculation. What is in debate here is if CSS rules affect content ranking.

Answer (score 2):

Some interesting answers on the topic here:  http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=9657#p36568

Also, if you ARE using Ajax, this may help:  http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/

Answer (score 2):

according to this blog post this practice is not good for google , you may get a penalty:
http://ocarbone.free.fr/blog/?p=222

The reason is that some black hat SEO techniques are based on hidden content, this topic is delicate.

> Matt Cutts from Google has talked
>   about this on his blog and basically
>   he says you shouldn't use
>   display:none; to hide content as it is
>   considered a form of cloaking

Some Seo advisers claims that you can use `display:none;` without any consequence as long as you are not using it for keyword stuffing and hidden links to others domains.

**UPDATE:**
After some research, I came up with some assumptions (assumptions because is not 100% guarantee unless you work at Google and know exactly how the indexing works).

-There is not automatic method to penalty a website using `display:none;` to hide content, this means all potentials cloaking cases are manually checked.

-You wont get penalty if the hidden content come visible by posterior user interaction ie: mouseover or click.

-The hidden content does get index by Google (if not why so much care by Google about the hidden content?, besides I have some really good scenarios that can prove this theory).

-If you are worried about google not indexing your hidden content you can use a technique call 'Progressive Enhancement' [CSS drop-down menu and SEO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408878/css-drop-down-menu-and-seo/2408915#2408915)

Comment: So what is the best solution to use tabs without any bad consequences? It's not a spam technique, there is a lot of strong content in these tabs, but using several different address missing a point.

Comment: Is not easy to tell because some people claim that it can be used as long as your are not using it to do keyword stuffing and hidden links.

Answer (score 1):

I've used jquery tabs as well as jquery sliders on sites and found not only that the rankings didn't suffer; they actually went up though I can't say it was because of the tabs but simply better content within them. The tabs are filled with content, no stuffing. All the content is indexed by google. I was worried about this issue myself but found no negative affects on rankings at all.

Answer (score 0):

Make the tabs a list of content-blocks and display all of them by default one following the other vertically. This way, even users without JavaScript will see all of the content, just not in tabs but as a vertically sequential list of content-blocks. Then, use JavaScript to make the content-blocks tabs and hide all but the first one after page-/content-load.

This will not only optimized SEO, but also accessibility for screen-readers etc, which may not understand JavaScript or not read `display:none` text.

Comment: Aesthetically it's not ideal to have all the tabs visible briefly just before the javascript kicks in, kind of makes the site look a little broken.